# Upgrade packages only from a specific repository

Tags: ansible, apt

I would like to perform an `apt-get upgrade` only for the packages existing in a specific repo.

I've been cheking in the [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html) and [apt_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_repository_module.html#apt-repository-module) modules and I don't find a way to force that, I can see that we can handle packages, but not complete repos.

Is that possible?

If not, Is there some workaround which could avoid using the shell module?

I thought something like using the [apt_repo](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_repo_module.html#apt-repo-module) module for deleting all the repositories, then adding my personal repo and executing the upgrade. But I can't figure out how to come back to the original repos after the upgrade is finished.

Comment: What is the command-line equivalent of what you'd like to implement in Ansible?

Comment: @VladimirBotka Something like `apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/my_repo.sources.list`

Comment: IMHO, It's not possible to pass such options to [apt](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py).

Answer (score 0):

From your provided information

```bash
apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/my_repo.sources.list
```

I understand that you like to set additional `other_options` similar to [`dpkg_options`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-dpkg_options) when using the [`apt` module – Manages apt-packages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html).

Since that feature isn't available

- you would either need to use the [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) and as already within the comments,
- or tweak the [source code of `apt.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py) and implement in an own fork the capability to use `other_options` similar to the available `dpkg_options`

  - [`DPKG_OPTIONS ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L378)
  - [`def expand_dpkg_options ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L605)
  - [`def install ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L705)
  - [`if build_dep:`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L782)
  - and so on ...

  up to the point were the feature is available for your needs.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to use the options `sourcelist`, `sourceparts`, `List-Cleanup` in Ansible `apt` module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75286840/6771046)