# How to use the options `sourcelist`, `sourceparts`, `List-Cleanup` in Ansible `apt` module?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ansible-module

I want to run the following `apt` command via an Ansible module.

```yaml
apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/mypackages.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"
```

I don't want to use the shell module for this purpose as follows.

```yaml
- name: update apt package manager with parameters
  shell: 'apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/mypackages.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"'
```

Later after executing the update, I am installing these packages,

```yaml
- name: install plugin and core package
  apt:
    pkg:
    - dump_plugin
    - core
    state: present
    allow_unauthenticated: yes
    update_cache: yes
```

How to use the options `sourcelist`, `sourceparts`, `List-Cleanup` in Ansible `apt` module?

Comment: `I don't want to use the shell module`. I'm affraid you won't have any other choice as there are no ways listed in the [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html) to set these kind of options.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator. Will go with shell if I don't find until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

From your currently provided information I understand that you like to set additional `other_options` similar to [`dpkg_options`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-dpkg_options) when using the [`apt` module – Manages apt-packages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html).

Since that feature isn't available currently

- you would either need to use the [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) and as already within the comments,

> ***I don't want to use the `shell` module***

- or tweak the [source code of `apt.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py) and implement in an own fork the capability to use `other_options` similar to the available `dpkg_options`

  - [`DPKG_OPTIONS ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L378)
  - [`def expand_dpkg_options ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L605)
  - [`def install ...`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L705)
  - [`if build_dep:`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L782)
  - and so on ...

  up to the point were the feature is available for your needs.